# Python: How do I multiply DataFrame values by number prior to a certain date

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetimeindex

Consider the following DataFrame:

```
df:
ticker           A        B        C
date
2022-01-02       145      100      100
2022-01-03       450      200      241
2022-01-04       100      200      NaN
2022-01-05       424      324      222
2022-01-06       400      421      320
```

I want to multiply the values in the columns prior to the date `2022-01-04` (included) for each column as follows:

For column A, I want to multiply by 2

For column B, I want to multiply by 8

For column C, I want to multiply by 4

The resulting DataFrame should look like this:

```
df2:
ticker           A        B        C
date
2022-01-02       290      800      400
2022-01-03       900      1600     964
2022-01-04       200      1600     NaN
2022-01-05       424      324      222
2022-01-06       400      421      320
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this

```
df.loc[df["ticker date"]<="2022-01-04", ["A", "B", "C"]] = df.loc[df["ticker date"]<="2022-01-04", ["A", "B", "C"]].apply(lambda x: [x["A"]*2, x["B"]*8, x["C"]*4], axis=1, result_type='broadcast')
```

Comment: That didn't work. Also, why didn't you add column A in the apply function?

Comment: You have to change the column names according to your need. I have used other column names thatswhy it didn't worked. Change the column names according to your need else let me do it.

Comment: @MathMan99 Now check, also please change the date column name.